# Can one method return a few files?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a method in asp.net mvc app that return a file.

```
public FileResult GetFile()
{
    ...
    return File(file_path,file_type,file_name);
}
```

But now a need to return a few different types files. Can one method do it? Or how to do it correctly?

Comment: Zip them up into a single zip file.

Answer (score 2):

Either return a .zip file that contains all files or return a list of urls, pointing to each file and let the browser download all files individually.